# How to change the custom view dynamically in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

First of all - I am a newbie to android. I've created some custom view classes as below.

- CustomViewBaseClass
- CustomViewOne extends CustomViewBaseClass
- CustomViewTwo extends CustomViewBaseClass
- CustomViewThree extends CustomViewBaseClass

In my layout file I've added CustomViewOne as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.test.custom.CustomViewOne
        android:id="@+id/cvone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is working fine as expected.

But I want to replace this CustomViewOne dynamically with CustomViewTwo/CustomViewThree on some events (button click etc...)

How to do this run-time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

casting them to `CustomViewBaseClass` makes the handling less complicated:

```
CustomViewBaseClass customView = (CustomViewBaseClass) findViewById(R.id.cvone);
mLinearLayout.removeView(customView);

customView = (CustomViewBaseClass) new CustomViewTwo(MainActivity.this);
mLinearLayout.addView(customView);
```

because otherwise, one would always have to check their class with `instanceof`.

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout parent = findViewById(R.id.parent);
CustomViewOne customViewOne = findViewById(R.id.cvone);
parent.removeView(customViewOne);

//Now Add your CustomViewTwo
CustomViewTwo customViewTwo = new CustomViewTwo(YourActivity.this);
parent.addView(customViewTwo);
```